# Colission detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple pokémon game for my cousin. It's kinda simple pikachu comes running from the right and ash moves on the right.

Only one problem when I press spacebar my pokébal flies from left to right but it doesn't detect any collision.

Can you help me?
Here the code :

js :

```
function goPika() {
  $("#pika").animate({ left : '5px' }, 2500);
  setInterval(function(){ 
    checkPosition();
  }, 100);

  function checkPosition() {
     var positionPika = $("#pika").position().left;
  }
}

function Throw() {
  $("#bal").animate({ marginLeft : "96%" }, 1000);
  setInterval(function(){ 
    checkPositionBal();
  }, 100);

  function checkPositionBal(){
     var positieBal = $("#bal").position().left;
     var positieBalCol = (positionBal + 200);
     console.log(positionBalCol);
   }
 };


function catch() {
   if (positionBalCol == positionPika) {
     console.log("collision");
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to put your variable names and function names in english so the english speakers here can better understand your code. Also, can you add a stack snippet of functional code?

Comment: You'd imagine it some sort of timing issue, perhaps console.log the positions and see if they match at any point?  I get the feeling that when a ball is moved then the collision detection has already been missed.

Comment: Where do you actually execute catch?

Comment: when the spaceBar is pressed,

Comment: @PeterS it is logged but the ball goes from 0 to -0.00000... while Pikachu goes from 780 to 5.

Comment: Shouldn't name your functions after Javascript keywords : `throw` and `catch`

Comment: @studentInNeed looks like the problem and is well explained below in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

first thing is : catch is a reserved keyword in javascript, so is throw...

Then, as pointed in another answer, your variables should be visible outside of your function (declared at the top).

Then moving the ball by an "animate" gives you no control on the actual displacement. UI should reflect the physics, and not the contrary.

Consider instead

```
var positionBalCol = 0;
var dt = 30.0;
setInterval(function() {
    positionBalCol += velocity * dt
}, dt);
```

Given you did all the above, you would still have and issue, with your collision test.

```
if (positionBalCol == positionPika)
```

is probably never true using floating point numbers because of some rounding on positionBalCol which gets accumulated through time.

Change the condition to

```
if (Math.abs(positionBalCol == positionPika) < 1.0E-4) // or whatever suitable threshold
```

Comment: Thanx, and catch and throw were dutch but I had to translate them

Comment: then just rename then "throwBall", and "catchBall"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables outside of the functions for them to be accessible to all functions. For example:

```
var positionBalCol,
    positionPika;

function checkPosition() {
    positionPika = $("#pika").position().left;
}
```

This stores `positionPika` outside of the `checkPosition` function. This way, you can later use it to compare it to `positionBalCol`.